# bash error ": =0: command not found"

Tags: bash

I have written a simple script and I wrote a function to check the return value and exit accordingly.

```
#!/bin/bash

function error_exit {
    echo "$1" 1>&2
    exit 1
}

function check_return_exit () {
    $OUT=$1
    if [[ $OUT != 1 ]]; then
        error_exit $2
    fi
}

function install_dependencies {
    apt-get install -y lxc expect
    EXIT_VAL=$?
    EXIT_MSG="Failed to install dependencies (lxc, expect)!!"
    check_return_exit $EXIT_VAL $EXIT_MSG
}

install_dependencies
```

I get this error when I launch my script. Can someone help me with this error?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
expect is already the newest version.
lxc is already the newest version.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  python-urllib3
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 90 not upgraded.
./launch_lxc.sh: line 9: =0: command not found
Failed
```

Comment: Try OUT="$1", actually, smart to quote most dollar dereferences.

Comment: FYI -- no need for the `function` keyword -- just `error_exit() {` for a POSIX-compliant function declaration; `function error_exit` just breaks POSIX compatibility but gives you no benefit.

Comment: ...also, all-caps is conventional for environment variables and builtins, not shell-local variables. Following this convention prevents namespace collisions.

Comment: @BrianTiffin No quotes needed there, though. Non-array assignments are not subject to word splitting/globbing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> $OUT=$1
> ^
> ```

You probably want to drop the `$`.